# Python tkinter: replace inputs with key presses?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to programming and python and have been writing a simple text-based RPG using the console for output and input. I want to change to using tkinter for text output into widgets and key input via keyboard presses. After getting the tkinter window layout how I want it I just can't figure out how to get the different inputs to use tkinter events.

```
def main_menu(hero):
choice = ' '
while choice not in ['0', '1', '2', '3']:
        while choice != '0' and hero.health > 0:
            print("\n" * 80)
            print(hero)
            print("Where would you like to go?\n"
                           "[1] Adventure\n"
                           "[2] Temple\n"
                           "[3] Store\n\n"
                           "[0] Save & Quit")
            choice = input(">")
            if choice == '1':
                adventure(hero)
            elif choice == '2':
                temple(hero)
            elif choice == '3':
                store(hero)
            elif choice == '0':
                save(hero)
```

And when an input for *choice* through tkinter has been made I want it to continue down into the next function for example *store()* where I want to get a new input from tkinter to resolve which function to call next

```
def store(hero):
    item_type = ''
    while item_type not in ['1', '2', '3']:
        print("\n" * 80)
        print("What would you like to buy?"
                   "\n[1] Weapons"
                   "\n[2] Armor"
                   "\n\n[3] Leave")
        item_type = str(input(">"))
        if item_type == '1':
            weapon_store(hero)
            item_type = ''
        elif item_type == '2':
            armor_store(hero)
            item_type = ''
        else:
            input("Okay, have a good day.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you correctly,

> I want to change to using tkinter for text output into widgets

For this purpose we use `Labels`. Let's take a short example:

```
var = StringVar()
label = Label( root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED )

var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
label.pack()
```

That's for setting a label.You take a string variable & you can change it anytime you want.

> key input via keyboard presses

```
def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)

def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()
```

If you run this script, you’ll find that you have to click in the frame before it starts receiving any keyboard events.

See more about [events and bindings at effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear about what my problem was. When I run the mainloop() to start the GUI I don't know how to make it enter the main_menu function without entering it every iteration of the main loop.
I have sorta understood the whole binding thing. What I want it to do is to initiate the GUI and then enter the main_menu() function and inside the different function I want to get a new input from the keyboard and have a good way of updating the different labels accordingly to whatever the input did in the function.

Comment: Then kindly re-frame your question before accepting your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by changing the key-pressed as a StringVar and then using wait_variable in the code where I want it to receive a new input.